# Scrollable GridView in Parent ScrollView is not working

Tags: android, xml, gridview

In my application I  need  to show two xml file into one xml,so I used  ScrollView layout  for that. But
In cardetails2 xml file I used GridView because I need to show data into row column format this Data is came from remote server  I bind this data into GridView.I made  GridView Scrollable because data is huge and I need to display only 3 rows at first.When I scroll GridView another rows will display.But when try to scroll gridView it is not working only parent scrollView is worked.Can any one know why it is not working.Already I have waste lot of time in googling.I am attaching xml files so get more idea.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#EFF1F0"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/car_details_header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="#000000"
                    android:layout_height="60dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_cardet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/back_btn" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardetails_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#848484" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_carname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/cardetails_price"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="40dp"
                  android:background="#01A9DB"
                  android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_cardetails_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardetails_main_context"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Deepak" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img1" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Second xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#EFF1F0"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:padding="5dp"   >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/cardetail_grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
            android:background="#ECCEF5">
        </GridView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_cardetails_req"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/request_quote_btn"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_cardetails_call"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/call_btn" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

  Here is main xml file


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#EFF1F0" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <include layout="@layout/cardetails"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

            <include layout="@layout/cardetails2"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>


        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: gridview it self have extended scrollview so its problem of scrollview inside scrollview and it wont work.

Comment: just remove scroll view if no need.

Comment: if i remove scroll view it shows gridView of data with no scroll.thats why used scrollview data is big that why i need to show first 3 rows.then user scroll the grid view

Comment: Gridview not required scrollView.

Comment: could you tell me where to need change in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Add scrollview to first xml :: like as below

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#EFF1F0"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/car_details_header"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:background="#000000"
                        android:layout_height="60dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_cardet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/back_btn" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cardetails_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#848484" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_carname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/cardetails_price"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="40dp"
                      android:background="#01A9DB"
                      android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_cardetails_price"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/cardetails_main_context"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Deepak" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/img1" />

        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
          </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know gridview is inherit from scrollView. so there are some problems during scrolling height calculation.
You could override OnMesure method of your gridview, and it can work well.

```
public class MyGridView extends GridView{

    public MyGridView (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    @Override 
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) { 
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(  
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);  
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);  

    } 
}
```

Then use MyGridView instead of GridView. you can scroll it.